# SQL substring Issue ( Where substring(...) = (select....) )

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I'm trying to search only the dirname from full path using this queries.

```
  SELECT 
      `file_name` FROM `tbl_files` where SUBSTR(`file_path`, 
        LOCATE('/',`file_path`)+1, 
          (CHAR_LENGTH(`file_path`) - LOCATE('/',REVERSE(`file_path`)) - LOCATE('/',`file_path`))) =
            (Select `source_path` from `tbl_transcode_folder` where `trancode_folder_id` = 1 )
```

But it return me nothing. When i replace `(Select source_path from tbl_transcode_folder where trancode_folder_id = 1 )` into it's result `mnt/hd/1` like the queries below , It's response want i to but i dont want to do in that way.

```
 SELECT 
          `file_name` FROM `tbl_files` where SUBSTR(`file_path`, 
            LOCATE('/',`file_path`)+1, 
              (CHAR_LENGTH(`file_path`) - LOCATE('/',REVERSE(`file_path`)) - LOCATE('/',`file_path`))) = `mnt/hd/1`
```

Comment: what is the common field between these two tables ??? Is there only one row in `tbl_transcode_folder where trancode_folder_id = 1` ???

Comment: there is no common fields between them,the other table stored the full path while the other table store dirname, is it possible even without common fields.? TIA

Comment: How is it possible that you are storing a file's full path and the directory name in two tables and there is no field in them tables???? how do you know which directory has what path ????

Comment: `tbl_transcode_folder` is far different in usage with `tbl_files`, i just want to scan all dirname in `tbl_files` base on the stored dirname in `tbl_transcode_folder`  which this table `tbl_files`  stored only the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your sub-query returns a random row from the table you need to define a relation between the `tbl_transcode_folder` table, you need to define a relation between the outer query and the sub-query to make them correlated

```
SELECT `file_name` 
FROM `tbl_files` 
where SUBSTR(`file_path`, LOCATE('/',`file_path`)+1
            ,(CHAR_LENGTH(`file_path`) - LOCATE('/',REVERSE(`file_path`)) 
            - LOCATE('/',`file_path`))) 
           =(Select `source_path` 
             from `tbl_transcode_folder` 
             where `trancode_folder_id` = 1 
             AND `tbl_files`.`CommonColumn` = `tbl_transcode_folder`.`CommonColumn`)
```

Comment: `Select file_name from tbl_files where UPPER(file_path) Like (Select source_path from tbl_transcode_folder where trancode_folder_id = 1 ) and media_type = 'video'` they have no common fields but return me what i want but when i need to change `LIKE` into `SUBSTR` return me nothing. TIA